# Import all CSV data and exported in a HTML email for report via Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I have a CSV file formatted with date, name, and timeToExpire. I want to send that CSV data in a email. I would like to create a HTML file.

When I run the code I received the email but with only one data and not all of that.

I know between the "here" and "end" I need to put a loop inside the body parameter. Or if you have another solution or option welcome on that.

```
$From = "System Administrator <sysadm@>"
$To = "pcisn@email.com"
#$Cc = "rn@email.com"
#$Attachment = "logs\pcemail.csv"
$Subject = "Passwd Reminder Report"

$users = import-csv -Path $csvfile | select *
foreach($user in $users)
{
   $date        = $user.'Date'
   $name        = $user.'name'
   $email       = $user.'EmailAddress'
   $expire      = $user.'DaystoExpire'
   $expireon    = $user.'ExpiresOn'
   $notify      = $user.'Notified'



    # Email Body Set Here, Note You can use HTML, including Images.
    $body ="

<table style= ""font-family: arial, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;"" >
  <tr style=""background-color: #f6f8f1;"" >
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">Date</th>
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">Name</th>
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">Email</th>
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">Days to Expire</th>
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">Expire On</th>
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">Was Notify?</th>
  </tr>

#=================== Here's the part that I need help ===========================
<tr style=""background-color: #dddddd;"">
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">$date</td>
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">$name</td>
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">$email</td>
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">$expire</td>
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">$expireon</td>
    <th style=""border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;"">$notify</td>
  </tr>
#================== end ================================
</table>

        <table width=""100%"" border=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" background=""#000000"">
            <tr style=""background-color: #000000;""  >
                <td align=""center""><font color=""#f6f8f1"">If you have any questions or issues, please contact us</font><br/>
                    <a href=""mailto:itt@ama.com""><font color=""#f6f8f1"">IT Support</font></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style=""background-color: #000000;"" >
                <td align=""center"" style=""padding: 20px 0 0 0;"">
                    <table border=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"">
                        <tr>
                            <td width=""37"" style=""text-align: center; padding: 0 10px 0 10px;"">
                                <a href=""http:///"">
                                    <img src=""https://s6.postimg.org/5rut/xs_blue_200.png"" width=""50"" height=""37"" alt=""AXS"" border=""0"" />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    "

    # Send Email Message
    #Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -credential $creds -from $from -to $email -subject $subject -body $body -bodyasHTML -usessl -port 587 -priority High

    Write-Host "Notificacion enviada a" $name

    } 
# End Send Message
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you man by "only one data"? Sharing a screenshot of the output might help me understand your issue.

Comment: I would expect your script to send many emails (with one row of data in each) - it's only sending one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code overwrites the Body field (and sends an email) on every iteration of the foreach loop... Basicly, what you are doing now is for every user : add the current user entry in the Body and mail this (and this happens for every entry in your input file). I also don't understand the "manual" construction of the HTML : Powershell has a native CMDlet for exporting to HTML, ConvertTo-HTML (you can use the -fragement parameter on this one to only output the  - adding custom formatting and styling can be done with CSS instead of applying them in-line)